# Why python version is different in Pycharm interpreter and Pycharm terminal

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have installed python 3.7.9 and 3.10.1. I have one virtual environment say(test). I have set up pycharm project interpreter as 3.7.9. But in the pycharm terminal, it is showing as 3.10.1, while in the interpreter it is 3.7.9. How to make them the same?

Comment: activate the environment you want in your pycharm terminal

Comment: Already did, but working

Comment: You can have many different version of Python installed in parallel. In Pycharm you set which interpreter you want, (the default for your project is in "setting, project".